# Issues with Android RFCOMM retransmissions

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am working with Android's [RFCOMM Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). I have it working, but I'm having an issue when I send large messages (this is intentional, and cannot be changed).

The issue is that I will see the same data transferred multiple times, but it stops after sending X bytes, even though N of those bytes were duplicates.

As an example, sending a chunk of 12800 bytes, my *receiving* side sees this data (cut down from the full log -- the numbers indicate the length of the string):

> Reading: (990)yJv;ZU>h8JCfAEttQEA7V9BSkITgDn5350SdahFILcbwrYAfD7b_Oavhqr:DF
>   Reading: (2970)HQTZWMFv08G3qHiHn@4_f8KWrQX9v]gmV=tvqGFpP:c8yV^a0i17:ndDiOS
>   Reading: (990)ZdXZvCxK5sdLlKDnPrrP;2nuEItZ9<\29e7x7lNFafHU]R@Ap=lBF\M?1\W_O
>   Reading: (990)ZdXZvCxK5sdLlKDnPrrP;2nuEItZ9<\29e7x7lNFafHU]R@Ap=lBF\M?1\W_O
>   Reading: (990)ZdXZvCxK5sdLlKDnPrrP;2nuEItZ9<\29e7x7lNFafHU]R@Ap=lBF\M?1\W_O
>   Reading: (1980)ZdXZvCxK5sdLlKDnPrrP;2nuEItZ9<\29e7x7lNFafHU]R@Ap=lBF\M?1\W_
>   Reading: (990)TD?lyEvS;[PMj>xpg5RiAIK8di61QNngkOvpoMhl=0`I@32iUuScR1xiGiZ:
>   Reading: (990)Ahyxc2PMA?sub8l^:prr=D5vIaGw73@rS0EHTeT;XLcsq9k6li;MVw_IJ4QiSs
>   Reading: (990)YQe:OWv_Iv_6eL@Yu>KUnbjmsN9KsidM1Vx6:LSsgZ[sbG3V>0dp7kkvUhX1^n
>   Reading: (920)YQe:OWv_Iv_6eL@Yu>KUnbjmsN9KsidM1Vx6:LSsgZ[sbG3V>0dp7kkvUhX1^n

As you can see, there are 3 exact retransmissions, and one retransmission that had more data appended. However, the sum of all the lengths is 12800 -- the original size of the message.

In case you're wondering, presently the data is just a random string. So, no, it's not getting the same bits of data in there more than once. And I have confirmed this by looking at the sending side.

Now, I need the data to come through without any corruption, so I'm checking a hash on the other side. However, with the retransmissions, and the lost data, it isn't matching most of the time. And cutting out the retransmissions just leaves me with missing data.

So, the issue seems to be two-fold:

1. Retransmissions are happening even though the data is received successfully.
2. Even when I'm smart about ignoring the retransmissions, all the data doesn't come through. If N bytes are retransmitted, I'm left with N bytes of missing data.

All relevant code for this has come directly from Android's website (link above). Key points of interest however are:

[Managing A Connection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection)

And this block, which comes from the [full code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat) from the tutorial I linked to:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() { 
     @Override 
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
         switch (msg.what) { 
         case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 
             if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1); 
             switch (msg.arg1) { 
             case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED: 
                 mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to); 
                 mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName); 
                 mConversationArrayAdapter.clear(); 
                 break; 
             case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING: 
                 mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting); 
                 break; 
             case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN: 
             case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE: 
                 mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected); 
                 break; 
             } 
             break; 
         case MESSAGE_WRITE: 
             byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj; 
             // construct a string from the buffer 
             String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf); 
             mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage); 
             break; 
         case MESSAGE_READ: 
             byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj; 
             // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer 
             String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1); 
             mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage); 
             break; 
         case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME: 
             // save the connected device's name 
             mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME); 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " 
                            + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             break; 
         case MESSAGE_TOAST: 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             break; 
         } 
     } 
 };
```